# +1 a website in Google search results using the keyboard

Tags: google-search, keyboard-shortcuts, google-plus-1

How do I +1 a website I see in Google search using the keyboard?

I love the use of arrow keys to navigate the search results and would like to +1 the websites I like. I don't want to move away from my keyboard to do it constantly.

Has anyone figured out the shortcut for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You tab until you get to it, then hit the enter key. I just tried it.

I like keyboard commands too, but this one is too much.